# Understanding QML Rotation Element

Tags: qt, qml

I think that first one out of the following states the point in the coordinate system where we wish to **place** the image. Correct?

What does the other one exactly say in layman's terms?

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qml-rotation.html#axis.x-prop

```
axis.x : real

axis.y : real

axis.z : real

The axis to rotate around. For simple (2D) rotation around a point, you do not need to specify an axis, as the default axis is the z axis (axis { x: 0; y: 0; z: 1 }).
```

and

```
origin.x : real

origin.y : real

The origin point of the rotation (i.e., the point that stays fixed relative to the parent as the rest of the item rotates). By default the origin is 0, 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not correct.

The first is the axis which will rotated. 
X is horizontal axis = Rotation will be to the viewer from top to bottom.
Y is vertical axis = Rotation will be to the viewer form left to right.
Z (the default) is perpendicular to the other 2 axis and is pointing to the viewer = Therefor rotation around Z is rotating on the screen-plane.

In the first parameter you just tell which axes to rotate around. So `axis(x:0; y:0; z:1)` just means to rotate on the screen plane.

The second are the origin-coordinates. This is the fixpoint where 0/0/0 of the axis coordinate system to rotate around is located. If this is the top-left corner of your object, you will rotate around that corner. You can rotate to any fixpoint, this also means: fixpoints other then the center point will always move your object.

Comment: Mathematical Rotation explained on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29